# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1 in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to the android studio, I downloaded this e-commerce template for learning.. I want to resolved the problem..his link I m download the code https://github.com/singhkshitij/MagicPrint-ECommerce-App-Android

My code build.gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'

implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
//google play services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'

implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.+'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'

implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'

implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

implementation('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.2@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'

implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'

implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+"

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'

implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+"

implementation 'com.webianks.library:easy-feedback:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.geniusforapp.fancydialog:FancyDialog:0.1.4'

implementation('com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:1.0.1@aar')

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'

implementation 'com.github.yesidlazaro:GmailBackground:1.2.0'

//Field and method binding for Android views which uses annotation processing
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'


implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'

//Libraries I've included
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'

//Stylish edittextbox
implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'

//radiogroup
implementation 'com.github.Gavras:MultiLineRadioGroup:v1.0.0.6'

//ticker textview
implementation 'com.tomer:fadingtextview:2.5'

// Dexter runtime permissions
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1'


implementation ("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.6@aar") {
    transitive = true
}

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried to sync this code but got an error

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: MagicPrint-ECommerce-App-Android-master-app
```

How to resolve... Thanks

Comment: Delete that library

Comment: You have to follow this setup: https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries#setup

Comment: @MohammadmoeinGolchin, I deleted the library but not working

Comment: Now what is your error?

Comment: Deleted this line:  implementation 'com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1'
Now Error Is : ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: MagicPrint-ECommerce-App-Android-master-app

Comment: Issue solved Now?

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1 Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

Open your **`build.gradle`** [Project level] . Make sure you added below

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
             google()
             jcenter()

            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" } // this is important
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.0.1
```

to

```
com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I visited their GitHub https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries followed the documentation and updated the version solved my problem.